# Why is this multi-threaded code faster than the sequential one, if the task is 100% on the CPU? - Python3.10

Tags: python, multithreading, gil

I have two simple code examples of the same calculation, which creates load on the CPU. The sequential one is significantly slower then the multi-threaded one. If I understand the concept of the GIL correctly, that should not be the case, as just one thread can run at the same time. So the overall time should be the same, as there is not wait time in I/O.

What could be an explanation for this? I have another example with the multiprocessing library, which runs even faster then the multi-threaded one, which is expected, as it creates load on 3 cores in parallel.

Sequential code - ~31 seconds:

```
import time

start_time = time.time()
my_threads = [100000000, 200000000, 300000000]
for x in my_threads:
    print(f"start {x}")
    for y in range(x):
        y*y
    print(f"finished input {x}: {time.time() - start_time:.2f} seconds")

print(f"{time.time() - start_time:.2f} seconds")
```

Multi-threaded code - ~15 seconds execution time:

EDIT: removed all unnecessary code, to make it simpler (does not change the outcome)

```
import threading
import time

def my_threaded_function(s, x):
    with s:
        start_time = time.time()
        for y in range(x):
            y*y
        print(f"finished input {x}: {time.time() - start_time:.2f} seconds")

s = threading.Semaphore(25)

my_threads = [100000000, 200000000, 300000000]
threads = []

start_time = time.time()

for x in my_threads:
    t = threading.Thread(
        target=my_threaded_function, name=f"Thread-{x}",
        args=(s, x,)
    )
    t.daemon = True
    threads.append(t)
    t.start()

[thread.join() for thread in threads]

print(f"{time.time() - start_time:.2f} seconds")
```

I expect the two examples to have the same execution time.

EDIT:
full output:

```
❯ python3 code/sequential.py
finished input 100000000: 4.57 seconds
finished input 200000000: 13.61 seconds
finished input 300000000: 27.09 seconds
27.09 seconds
❯ python3 code/threading_example.py
finished input 100000000: 7.84 seconds
finished input 200000000: 12.44 seconds
finished input 300000000: 14.65 seconds
14.68 seconds
```

Comment: I just ran this example with increased number of calculations / threads, by replacing the loop `for x in my_threads:` with `for x in range(25000):`
The result is that the threaded code is just very slightly faster (~1%). Both are around 15 seconds.

Comment: added the execution time for the sequential run - thanks @Clifford

Comment: `my_threads` items in threaded version have one more zeros. Was that intentional?

Comment: Your sequential code runs **much** faster than the multithreaded code in my environment (Python 3.12.1, Apple M2). You are not testing like with like as the my_threads list is different in each case. What is the purpose / value of the ActivePool class. As far as I can tell, all it does is to add unnecessary overhead

Comment: Damn just found this as well. Sorry, copy / paste error.
I ran both with the same elements `100000000, 200000000, 300000000`.
I updated the code in the original post to be correct.

This was not the reason, the timings I posted are correct.

Comment: In regards to the pool @CtrlZ, I removed all unnecessary code to make the code easier. This does not change the outcome.

Comment: Your sequential code is all running in global scope, which has different, slower performance characteristics. Try it in a function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason is that in the sequential code, you have global variables for reading and writing but in the threaded code, the variables are local.

Local variables are stored(STORE_FAST) and loaded(LOAD_FAST) much faster because the namespace of the functions are actually an array, instead of the dictionary and Python accesses them by index.

Put all the code in the sequential code in a function and run that again. You'll see that they are almost the same.

Having:

```py
for i in range(n):
    x = i * i
```

In the first line of the for loop, you store the returned number in `i`. In the second line, you look up `i` twice (i * i) and store `x`. These are all slower in global namespace.

Answer (score 0):

You can simplify the code to eliminate scoping issues and you'll observe that the sequential and multithreaded timings are very similar. multiprocessing is, not surprisingly, significantly faster in this case.

The results will also vary depending on your system architecture and, potentially, your Python version.

```
from threading import Thread
from timeit import timeit
from multiprocessing import Process

vlist = [10_000_000, 20_000_000, 30_000_000]

def calc(n):
    return n + n

def process(n):
    for _n in range(n):
        calc(_n)

def sq():
    for n in vlist:
        process(n)

def mt():
    threads = []

    for n in vlist:
        (thread := Thread(target=process, args=(n,))).start()
        threads.append(thread)

    for thread in threads:
        thread.join()

def mp():
    processes = []

    for n in vlist:
        (proc := Process(target=process, args=(n,))).start()
        processes.append(proc)

    for proc in processes:
        proc.join()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    for t, f in ("Sequential", sq), ("Multithreaded", mt), ("Multiprocessed", mp):
        print(t, "{:.4f}".format(timeit(f, number=1)))
```

**Output:**

```
Sequential 2.1882
Multithreaded 2.1827
Multiprocessed 1.1949
```

**Platform:**

```
macOS 14.3.1
Silicon M2
Python 3.12.1
```